# Simple way to write SQL query for select all data of linked tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I want to return the data of all the tables linked together via foreign keys when the tables are linked together in a chain. Is there a simple SQL command for this?

**SAMPLE DATA:** A entrance has floor_id fk to floors table, floor table has a building_id fk to buildings, buildings has a company_id fk to companies.

Can I get all the above data given just the entrance id?

Is there a more elegant way to do this then the following SQL:

```
    SELECT * FROM floor_entrance 
    LEFT JOIN floor ON floor.id = (SELECT floor_id FROM floor_entrance WHERE id = {floor_entrance_id})
    LEFT JOIN building ON building.id = (SELECT building_id FROM floor WHERE id = 
        (SELECT floor_id FROM floor_entrance WHERE id = {floor_entrance_id}))
    LEFT JOIN company ON company.id = (SELECT company_id FROM building WHERE id = 
        (SELECT building_id FROM floor WHERE id = 
            (SELECT floor_id FROM floor_entrance WHERE id = {floor_entrance_id})))
    WHERE floor_entrance.id = {floor_entrance_id}
```

I am looking to achieve a concise way to write this postgreSQL command.

**DESIRED RESULTS:** "LEFT JOIN ALL ON FOREIGN KEYS ACROSS THE WHOLE SCHEMA"?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, is the way I wrote my sql the best way to do it at least?

Comment: @Zaffer . . . Who knows?  You haven't described what you are trying to accomplish, nor have you provided sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply do it like this

```
SELECT * FROM floor_entrance A
LEFT JOIN floor B ON A.floor_id = B.id 
LEFT JOIN building C ON B.building_id = C.id 
LEFT JOIN company D ON C.company_id = D.id 
WHERE A.id = {floor_entrance_id}
```

Comment: ofcourse! I actually did sql like this before but I forget you can do it this way. SQL seems to one of those languages your forget quickly if you don't keep practicing.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no one simple way to do this. However the answer by @Alexis.Rolland is a neat way to do this even though you must left join each table manually.